# Writing data into MySql in pandas tosql in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am inserted data successfully. but i want to get the result whether data is inserted or not. my code is:

```
unit_type.to_sql(con=self.mysql_hermes.conn, name='CiqHistEleData',
                                                     if_exists='append', flavor='mysql', index=False)
```

i want result in one variable true or false.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to mark the answer as correct as discussed so that it would be usefull to others. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that's not going to work because the to_sql method does not return a value. The usual approach in pandas is to raise exceptions rather than return True/False so in the same spirit you will have to sorround your code with try/except. TypeError and ValueError are two typical exceptions raised by to_sql

```
try:
    unit_type.to_sql(con=self.mysql_hermes.conn, name='CiqHistEleData',
                                                     if_exists='append', flavor='mysql', index=False)
    # save successfull
except TypeError:
    # save failed write some code

    pass
except ValueError:
    # save failed write some code

    pass
```

Comment: Yup I think this is the solution using try catch but i try to find some other solution, np i will do with this solution. Thanks.. @e4c5

Comment: for another solution to exist it will have to return a value which it does not. You will have to catch these exceptions anyway because if you don't your program will fail so this is the one and only option :-)

Comment: Ok, and Thanks..@e4c5